# subtable does not align properly

Tags: tables

I tried to align 2 tables to save space using `\subtables` as shown [here](https://it.overleaf.com/learn/latex/How_to_Write_a_Thesis_in_LaTeX_(Part_3):_Figures,_Subfigures_and_Tables). So the same piece of code it turns out to be like this:
[image]

To ease the reader I will attach the piece of latex here:

```
\documentclass{article} % For LaTeX2e
\usepackage{iclr2021_conference,times}

% Optional math commands from https://github.com/goodfeli/dlbook_notation.
\input{math_commands.tex}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{url}
% add by yang
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{wrapfig,lipsum,booktabs}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{floatflt}
\usepackage{wrapfig,lipsum,booktabs}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
    \begin{subtable}[c]{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{l | l | l}
        Day & Max Temp & Min Temp \\
        \hline \hline
        Mon & 20 & 13\\
        Tue & 22 & 14\\
        Wed & 23 & 12\\
        Thurs & 25 & 13\\
        Fri & 18 & 7\\
        Sat & 15 & 13\\
        Sun & 20 & 13
       \end{tabular}
       \caption{First Week}
       \label{tab:week1}
    \end{subtable}
    \hfill
    \begin{subtable}[c]{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{l | l | l}
        Day & Max Temp & Min Temp \\
        \hline \hline
        Mon & 17 & 11\\
        Tue & 16 & 10\\
        Wed & 14 & 8\\
        Thurs & 12 & 5\\
        Fri & 15 & 7\\
        Sat & 16 & 12\\
        Sun & 15 & 9
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{Second Week}
        \label{tab:week2}
     \end{subtable}
     \caption{Max and min temps recorded in the first two weeks of July}
     \label{tab:temps}
\end{table}
```

Any thoughts why I get these tabs misaligned?

-- edit --
I have added the packages.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE. Could you edit your post to extend your code snippet to a minimum working example? Your code should start with a `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Add `\usepackage{subcaption}` to your preamble.

Comment: I guess you received an error message such as " Environment subtable undefined"  upon trying to compile your code. Please never ever ignore error messages! Even if you get something that on first glance resembles a pdf file, there can still be issues with it. After an error, TeX only tries to recover enough to syntax check more of the file, it does not try to make sensible output after an error.Thus, try to fix the all error messages before even taking a look at the resulting pdf file.

Comment: Completing your snippet with the necessary preamble shows no problem.

Comment: I have addedd the packages and the style (it's ICLR conference template)

Answer (score 1):

A minimal (non)working example that reproduces something close to your screenshot would be the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
    \begin{subtable}[c]{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{l | l | l}
        Day & Max Temp & Min Temp \\
        \hline \hline
        Mon & 20 & 13\\
       \end{tabular}
       \caption{First Week}
       \label{tab:week1}
    \end{subtable}
    \hfill
    \begin{subtable}[c]{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{l | l | l}
        Day & Max Temp & Min Temp \\
        \hline \hline
        Mon & 17 & 11\\
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{Second Week}
        \label{tab:week2}
     \end{subtable}
     \caption{Max and min temps recorded in the first two weeks of July}
     \label{tab:temps}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Trying to compile the above example results in a bunch of error message with the first one being

```
 LaTeX Error: Environment subtable undefined.
```

This error message is shown because you fogrot to add the `subcaption` package, which defines the `subtable` environment. Fixin the above example by adding `\usepackage{subcaption}` to the preamble results in the following code that compiles without error messages and results in the following expected output:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
    \begin{subtable}[c]{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{l | l | l}
        Day & Max Temp & Min Temp \\
        \hline \hline
        Mon & 20 & 13\\
       \end{tabular}
       \caption{First Week}
       \label{tab:week1}
    \end{subtable}
    \hfill
    \begin{subtable}[c]{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{l | l | l}
        Day & Max Temp & Min Temp \\
        \hline \hline
        Mon & 17 & 11\\
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{Second Week}
        \label{tab:week2}
     \end{subtable}
     \caption{Max and min temps recorded in the first two weeks of July}
     \label{tab:temps}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

---

Conclusion: Do not ignore error messages! Even if you get something that on first glance resembles a pdf file, there can still be issues with it. After an error, TeX only tries to recover enough to syntax check more of the file, it does not try to make sensible output after an error. Thus, try to fix the all error messages before even taking a look at the resulting pdf file. If you don't know what to do in order to fix such an error message, you could ask a question explicitly mentioning the error messages you get.

Since you mentioned one of the Overleaf How To... pages, I assume you use Overleaf to compile your code. If that's correct, you should see someting like the following:

[image]

If you click on the button with the "6"  inside of a red rectangle you can see the error messages. Only take a look at the output, if there is no red rectangle. (= no error messages)

Comment: Hi, no actually I included subcaption, but I still get the same misalignment

Comment: I actually get this error which it does not make sense: 
Package subcaption Error: This package can't be used in cooperation (subfigure)
I mean, if I want to put tables aside I might be willing to do the same for figures, why this is not possible?

Comment: Your document seems to also load the deprecated subfigure  package. The packages subfigure and subcaption are mutually incompatible, this is what the error message refers to. Just remove the subfigure package. The subcaption package not only supports subtable but also subfigures.