# Subplot does not give expected results

Tags: floats, subplot

I used subplot code presented by overleaf and the only thing I change was adding my own figures. The result is totally wrong :) I thought it may be the problem of the size but even by adjusting the at `\includegraphics` was the same. Could you tell me what I am doing wrong ?

```
\begin{figure}
     \centering
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Figures_FCM/maturityf.eps}
         \caption{$y=x$}
         \label{fig:y equals x}
     \end{subfigure}
     \hfill
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Figures_FCM/colorf.eps}
         \caption{$y=3sinx$}
         \label{fig:three sin x}
     \end{subfigure}
     \hfill
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Figures_FCM/aggregate.eps}
         \caption{$y=5/x$}
         \label{fig:five over x}
     \end{subfigure}
        \caption{Three simple graphs}
        \label{fig:three graphs}
\end{figure}
```

The result takes the whole page and the 3rd image goes beyond the page...
[image]

Comment: Did you add the subcaption package to your preamble?

Comment: Althoug about `subtable`s rather than about `subfigure`s, the following answer should also help you get the expected output: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/565200/134144