# How to make the space between coefficient and standard errors smaller from Stata on LaTeX?

Tags: tables, stata

[image]I used outreg command to get the following tex code, yet I cannot find how to make the coefficients and their standard errors as close as possible.

The code goes as follows:

The preamble:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\setlength{\pdfpagewidth}{12in} \setlength{\pdfpageheight}{11in}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,includeheadfoot,margin=2.5 cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{cases} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[symbol]{footmisc}

\RequirePackage{etex}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\linespread{1.5}
```

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\begin{adjustbox}{width=\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{lcccccc} \hline \hline
 & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) & (5) & (6) \\
 & ic7d & ic14d & ic7d & ic14d & ic7d & ic14d \\ \hline
 &   \\
\textbf{c7} & 0.003   \sym{}\\
 & (0.0025)   \\
\textbf{c14} &  & 0.003   \sym{}\\
 &  & (0.0025)   \\
\textbf{avrg7} &  &  & -0.502*  \sym{}\\
 &  &  & (0.2030)  \\
\textbf{avrg14} &  &  &  & -0.506* \sym{}\\
 &  &  &  & (0.2070)  \\
\textbf{dg7} &  &  &  &  & 1.257**   \sym{}\\
 &  &  &  &  & (0.2980) &  \\
\textbf{dg14} &  &  &  &  &  & 1.261** \sym{}\\
 &  &  &  &  &  & (0.3010) \\
\textbf{Number of Obs.} & 1,453 & 1,402 & 1,424 & 1,373 & 1,377 & 1,326 \\
\textbf{R-squared} & 0.001 & 0.001 & 0.093 & 0.093 & 0.169 & 0.170 \\
 \hline \hline 
\multicolumn{7}{\linewidth}{\small Robust standard errors in parentheses; + p$<$0.1, * p$<$0.05, ** p$<$0.01} \\
\multicolumn{7}{\linewidth}{\small Table 1} \\
\multicolumn{7}{\linewidth}{\small The regressions are of 7 days of lags.} \\
\end{tabular}
 \  \end{adjustbox}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Tex. Please provide a full compileable code inclduing the preamble  so that others can analyse your problem easier.

Comment: Thank you, I am new here. I also updated with code fences!

Comment: Your code currently is not compilable. The second argument of `\multicolumn{7}{\linewidth}` for example is wrong. Probably you wanted to use `\multicolumn{7}{p{\linewidth}}` instead? On the other hand, a simple `\multicolumn{7}{l}` should already be sufficient. Also, the combination of `cases` and `amsmath` as it currently is in your preamble, leads to an error message such as "Command \subequations already defined". Switch the load order of the two packages in order to get rid of that error message.

Comment: Is there a reason for which you decided to manually number the table and place the caption text inside of a `\multicolumn` command instead of using the usual `\caption` command and automatically numbered tables?

Comment: I have used Stata's outreg command to come up with this tables. It automatically gives me a table format of such. The code is compilable in Overleaf, probably you are using TeXMaker or such @leandriis

Comment: @countercyclical24: Using overleaf or texmaker should not make a difference here. Are you sure, the code compiles without error messages for you? Overleaf is pretty good at "hiding"  them from their users. Look for a red rectangls with a white number on it, such as the one shown at the end of this old answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/565200/134144

Comment: Yes I found them and fixed them. Many thanks. Do you know how can I make the space between the coefficients and standard errors smaller? I want them to be near, as close as possible. For example, 0.003 being directly above 0.0025 (under ic7d)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117322/discussion-between-countercyclical24-and-leandriis).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question, I assume you want the linespacing to only affect the text, while keeping a smaller linespacing while inside of a table. If that's the correct assumption, using the `setspace` package, that automatically takes care of that, might be interesting for you. In the following MWE, I also made some more changes to the preamble and the table code itself to further improve the output:

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
%\setlength{\pdfpagewidth}{12in} \setlength{\pdfpageheight}{11in} % seems to contradict the geometry package options you set, therefore removed
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % default with up to date latex
\usepackage[a4paper,includeheadfoot,margin=2.5 cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath} % switched load order to prevent error messages
\usepackage{cases}
%\usepackage{adjustbox} % not needed any more, since adjustbox environment around table was removed. Using adjustbox on a table makes font sized inconsistent. If you insist on a table that is exactly as wide as the textwidth, take a look at the second example.

%%%% unrelated to the table issue: %%%%
%\usepackage[symbol]{footmisc}
%\RequirePackage{etex}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{imakeidx}
%\usepackage[round]{natbib}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{setspace} % replacement for \linespread. Only afects text, does not change line spacing inside of tables
\doublespacing

\usepackage{caption} % improve spacing around caption, offers ways to change the caption's style
\usepackage{booktabs} % for horizontal lines with improved spacing


\usepackage{lipsum} % just for dummy text. Do not use in real document.



\begin{document}
\lipsum[4]


\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{The regressions are of 7 days of lags.}
\begin{tabular}{lcccccc} 
\toprule
 & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) & (5) & (6) \\
 & ic7d & ic14d & ic7d & ic14d & ic7d & ic14d \\ 
 \midrule
\textbf{c7} & 0.003   \\
 & (0.0025)   \\
\textbf{c14} &  & 0.003   \\
 &  & (0.0025)   \\
\textbf{avrg7} &  &  & -0.502*  \\
 &  &  & (0.2030)  \\
\textbf{avrg14} &  &  &  & -0.506* \\
 &  &  &  & (0.2070)  \\
\textbf{dg7} &  &  &  &  & 1.257**   \\
 &  &  &  &  & (0.2980) &  \\
\textbf{dg14} &  &  &  &  &  & 1.261** \\
 &  &  &  &  &  & (0.3010) \\
\textbf{Number of Obs.} & 1,453 & 1,402 & 1,424 & 1,373 & 1,377 & 1,326 \\
\textbf{R-squared} & 0.001 & 0.001 & 0.093 & 0.093 & 0.169 & 0.170 \\
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{7}{l}{\small Robust standard errors in parentheses; + p$<$0.1, * p$<$0.05, ** p$<$0.01} 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{The regressions are of 7 days of lags.}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lcccccc} 
\toprule
 & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) & (5) & (6) \\
 & ic7d & ic14d & ic7d & ic14d & ic7d & ic14d \\ 
 \midrule
\textbf{c7} & 0.003   \\
 & (0.0025)   \\
\textbf{c14} &  & 0.003  \\
 &  & (0.0025)   \\
\textbf{avrg7} &  &  & -0.502*  \\
 &  &  & (0.2030)  \\
\textbf{avrg14} &  &  &  & -0.506* \\
 &  &  &  & (0.2070)  \\
\textbf{dg7} &  &  &  &  & 1.257**   \\
 &  &  &  &  & (0.2980) &  \\
\textbf{dg14} &  &  &  &  &  & 1.261** \\
 &  &  &  &  &  & (0.3010) \\
\textbf{Number of Obs.} & 1,453 & 1,402 & 1,424 & 1,373 & 1,377 & 1,326 \\
\textbf{R-squared} & 0.001 & 0.001 & 0.093 & 0.093 & 0.169 & 0.170 \\
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{7}{l}{\small Robust standard errors in parentheses; + p$<$0.1, * p$<$0.05, ** p$<$0.01} 
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great! Many thanks, you saved my output